# Newbie installing ESLint in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been using vi and emacs for years, but I just installed VS Code, and I changed a file association so VS Code knows my file contains JavaScript code.  I got a message suggesting that I install ESLint by "using 'npm install -g eslint'."  Where do I type this command?  Do I need to, for example, launch a Windows Command Prompt to execute this command?  I am running VS Code under Windows at the moment, but I also installed VS Code on my desktop, which runs Linux, so I imagine I will need to go through the same customization on my desktop as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just press ctrl+` in VS Code. This combination lets you open built-in vscode terminal then you can launch `npm i -g eslint`. In Linux you must also add `sudo` before any npm packge you want to install globaly.
I suggest you to read about vscode shortcuts in main menu settings or something like this. Hope this would be helpful

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help.  I got a message saying "PS X:\> npm install -g eslint" on one line, and "npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." on the next line.  (The first line is the command I typed in.)  How do I fix that?Something that's not clear to me is whether I first need go to the market place and search for and download the ESLint plug in (or even if I need to go to the market place in the first place), and then type this command, or if it's the other way around.

Comment: Looks like you have no npm/node installed. To fix this just install node from https://nodejs.org/en/ and then try to launch `npm i -g eslint` again

Comment: after that when you have successfully installed eslint you should enable eslint package in vscode by installing extension from marketplace https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint